# WCF System.OutOfMemoryException while reading file - no streaming

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7.5

i have a WCF service which reads a binary file, the size of it is 4 908 292 108 byte (4.57 GB), the code works fine in my local machine but when i deploy it in IIS (7.5) it start to throw System.OutOfMemoryException.

I'm using this code to read it:

```
Friend Function ClipRectangle(ByVal Extent As MetricRectangle) As List(Of ShelterFeatureLine)

    Dim FileStream As FileStream
    Dim Reader As BinaryReader
    Dim OutputList As List(Of ShelterFeatureLine)
    Dim OneBlockResult As ShelterFeatureLine

    FileStream = New FileStream(mFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Reader = New BinaryReader(FileStream)

    OutputList = New List(Of ShelterFeatureLine)

    Try
        Do While Not Reader.BaseStream.Position >= Reader.BaseStream.Length
            OneBlockResult = ProcessOneBlock(Reader, Extent)

            If Not OneBlockResult Is Nothing Then
                OutputList.Add(OneBlockResult)
            End If
        Loop
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message & vbNewLine & "Reader.BaseStream.Position=" & Reader.BaseStream.Position & "/" & Reader.BaseStream.Length)
    End Try

    Reader.Close()
    FileStream.Close()
    Reader.Dispose()
    FileStream.Dispose()

    Return OutputList

End Function


Function ProcessOneBlock(ByVal Reader As BinaryReader, ByVal Extent As MetricRectangle) As ShelterFeatureLine

    Dim Porosity As Double
    Dim Height As Double
    Dim CountOfPoints As Integer
    Dim PointIndexBaseOne As Integer
    Dim LocationX As Double
    Dim LocationY As Double
    Dim DoUseThisLine As Boolean
    Dim PointsBaseZero() As MetricCoordinate
    Dim OneShelterFeatureLine As ShelterFeatureLine


    Porosity = Reader.ReadDouble
    Height = Reader.ReadDouble
    CountOfPoints = Reader.ReadInt32
    DoUseThisLine = False
    ReDim PointsBaseZero(CountOfPoints - 1)
    For PointIndexBaseOne = 1 To CountOfPoints
        LocationX = Reader.ReadDouble
        LocationY = Reader.ReadDouble 
        PointsBaseZero(PointIndexBaseOne - 1).X = LocationX
        PointsBaseZero(PointIndexBaseOne - 1).Y = LocationY
        If DoesPointLieInRectangle(Extent, LocationX, LocationY) Then
            DoUseThisLine = True
        End If
    Next
    If DoUseThisLine Then
        OneShelterFeatureLine = New ShelterFeatureLine(PointsBaseZero)
        With OneShelterFeatureLine
            .Porosity = Porosity
            .Height = Height
        End With
    End If

    If Not OneShelterFeatureLine Is Nothing Then
        Return OneShelterFeatureLine
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If


End Function
```

and always i get the exception when i reach: Reader.BaseStream.Position=4256694484 of 4908292108
with 651597624 byte left

I even tried to split the file in two parts and call twice ClipRectangle, but  on the seconth file, while there are 651597624 byte missing, it stops:
Reader.BaseStream.Position=1208792016/1860389640

Anybody can see anything wrong or knows some IIS setting responsible to fix this problem?